# How to apply fields filter on nested object in loopback model query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, loopback

I have this data on mongodb in a table named "Alerts" in geojson format

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5be40b8099d5b81e6115d517"),
"title" : "Real-time earthquake",
"priority" : "high",
"status" : NumberInt("1"),          
"extAlertData" : {
                 "type" : "Feature",
                  "properties" : {
                                  "mag" : 4.11,
                                  "place" : "12km S of Tres Pinos, CA",
                                  "time" : 1541163534230,
                                  },
                  "geometry" : {
                                 "type" : "Point",
                                 "coordinates" : [
                                                 -121.3146667,
                                                 36.6801667,
                                                 6.48
                                                 ]
                               },
                   "id" : "nc73105276"
                 }
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5be401c39b9e021a4c1a5c80"),
"title" : "Real-time earthquake",
"priority" : "high",
"status" : NumberInt("1"),          
"extAlertData" : {
                  "type" : "Feature",
                  "properties" : {
                                  "mag" : 4.5,
                                  "place" : "107km NW of Tobelo, 
                                             Indonesia",
                                  "time" : 1541665816710,
                                 },
                  "geometry" : {
                               "type" : "Point",
                               "coordinates" : [
                                               127.2763,
                                               2.3671,
                                               31.55
                                               ]
                               },
                   "id" : "us1000hp6t"
                 }
}
```

I want to retrieve the field "id" which is nested inside "extAlertData" using model query.

Following query does not working.

```
db.Alerts.find({fields : {"extAlertData.id": true}},
                        function (err, Alerts){
                            //process alert extAlertData.id
                        }
});
```

Query is retrieving the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

How can I query using fields filter in mongoDB? I am using loopback framework of node js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use $exists if you are looking to check the existence of 'id' filed db.Alerts.find( { 'extAlertData.id': { $exists: true}}). And i guess the part '{fields : ' i wrong in your query

Comment: Sorry. I am not looking for existence of 'id' field in db. I have array of similar object in the given format as specified in the question.I am trying to get all "extAlertData.id" and save to an array.

Comment: Then you need to check if it exists in the record and then project it

Comment: can you please help me with the query? How to specify to get all "extAlertData.id"

Comment: could you post the expected output

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet : expected output is array of id's : [nc73105276, us1000hp6t]

Comment: You can use aggregation for this `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      ids: {
        $push: "$extAlertData.id"
      }
    }
  }
])`

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/EfDYxGUJw_v

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet . It's working.I got the expected output.Thank you so much

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet If i want a result like [{id:'nc73105276',time:'1541163534230'},{id:'us1000hp6t',time:'1541665816710'}]
Then how can use this query?That is, i want to retrieve id and time as an array of object

Comment: Hi @Annie If you need something else then please ask a new question then I can easily explain you.